# com.spatial4j.core.exception.InvalidShapeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, solr, lucene, geospatial, numberformatexception

I am using following field type with solr 4.2 & its working fine.

```
          <field name="latlong" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />

          <fieldType name="location_rpt"   class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
           distErrPct="0.025"
           maxDistErr="0.000009"
           units="degrees"
        />
```

But, when I am upgrading solr to solr 4.7.1, it is reporting following errors while posting new docs:

```
       Caused by: com.spatial4j.core.exception.InvalidShapeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "78.42968,30.73333,78.45"
    at org.apache.solr.util.SpatialUtils.parsePoint(SpatialUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.solr.util.SpatialUtils.parsePointSolrException(SpatialUtils.java:84)
    ... 45 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "78.42968,30.73333,78.45"

I am posting following doc value to solr.

```
       <field name='latlong'><![CDATA[30.9308,78.42968,30.73333,78.45]]></field>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 Values in the String. If I read the documentation correct it will only expect `x,y`.

Comment: Jens: Thanks for the reply. It worked for me. Actually, there are 4 values in the string. But solr 4.2 was accepting it(could be a bug with that & I never noticed it before), but solr 4.7.1 reported it as error. How I figured it out & its working. Thanks :)